# Swift How to filter an array within an array

Tags: arrays, swift, struct, filter, searchbar

I have an array defined as:

```
var MyArrayOfPaintings = [Painting]()
```

where Painting is defined as:

```
struct Painting{
    let Artist: String
    let Name: String
    let ThumbNailURL: String
    var PaintsUsed: [Paint]
}
```

and Paint is defined as:

```
struct Paint{
    var PaintType: String
    var PaintColorName: String
}
```

Normally if I want to filter this array based on the Name property within my search bar I would simply add a line as such:

```
FilteredArray = MyArrayOfPaintings.filter({$0.Name.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())})
```

This works fine, but now inside my search bar I would also like to be able to search and then filter on MyArray where PaintColorName is the searched value.

How can I filter MyArrayOfPaintings based an a PaintColourName that is provided how do you essentially filter an array based on a array of structs inside it?

Comment: In the same way. You just need to ask, of each painting, whether any of the paints used has this as its color.

Comment: Also please start property names and variable names with a minuscule. Capitals are for types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not related to your question but you can use localizedCaseInsensitiveContains instead of lowercasing name and search text. Regarding your question you can filter the paints that contains the color name.

```
struct Painting {
    let artist: String
    let name: String
    let thumbNailURL: String
    var paints: [Paint]
}
```

---

```
struct Paint {
    var type: String
    var colorName: String
}
```

---

```
var paintings: [Painting] = [.init(artist: "Artist A", name: "Name A", thumbNailURL: "url1", paints: [.init(type: "a", colorName: "white"), .init(type: "b", colorName: "black")]),
                             .init(artist: "Artist B", name: "Name B", thumbNailURL: "url2", paints: [.init(type: "c", colorName: "red"), .init(type: "d", colorName: "green")])]
```

---

```
let searchText = "green"
let filtered = paintings.filter { $0.paints.contains {$0.colorName.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchText) } }

print(filtered) // [Painting(artist: "Artist B", name: "Name B", thumbNailURL: "url2", paints: [Paint(type: "c", colorName: "red"), Paint(type: "d", colorName: "green")])]
```

If you would like to get only the paint you can use flatMap instead of filter and then filter instead of contains:

```
let paints = paintings.flatMap { $0.paints.filter {$0.colorName.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchText) } }

paints  // [{type "d", colorName "green"}]
```

Comment: Thank you this helped, also did not realise the case insensitive function helps save another line of transforms. Thank you